# Select Every Nth Record From SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am having a Database in which data is been logged in regular interval of time i e for 5 minutes say it is been logged for 24 hours as shown in below table.

```
       Date and Time        Value
    2016-09-17 14:00:00      25.26
    2016-09-17 14:05:00      24.29
    2016-09-17 14:10:00      25.22
    2016-09-17 14:20:00      25.10





    2016-09-17 23:55:00      20.21
```

I want To display Every 1 hour reading using SQL query There are chances the some reading may be missing The expected Output should be.

```
     Date and Time        Value
    2016-09-17 14:00:00      25.26
    2016-09-17 15:00:00      27.29
    2016-09-17 16:00:00      28.12
    2016-09-17 17:00:00      22.11
```

There are chances my be that some reading may be missing. like

```
       Date and Time        Value
    2016-09-17 14:35:00      25.26
```

This reading may be missing
Please Suggest SQL query for the same

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: Please consider another approach, try reading the rows with zero in minutes and seconds instead of reading every Nth record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.DateCol,
       t1.Value
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(DateCol) AS firstDate
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY FORMAT(DateCol, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh')
) t2
    ON t1.DateCol = t2.firstDate
```

If you instead wanted to group by every 15 minutes, you could try:

```
GROUP BY CONCAT(FORMAT(DateCol, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh'),
                FLOOR(DATEPART(MINUTE, DateCol) / 15))
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working Fine but still one doubt if the interval is not for hour say i want to see at any time interval may be 15mins ,30mins and so on

Comment: @Lalit I updated my answer.  For 15 minutes, for example, you could add a term to the grouping for the quarter hour.